# Typographic conventions for free space between subfigures?

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats, typography

I'm trying to define a "standard template" for drawing figures for my Ph. D. thesis.
I would design large figures to fill the whole textwidth. Sometimes, however I have smaller figure, so that 2 (rarely 3) fit on "one line", and I also want to create a template for them with `width`<`0.5 \textwidth` resp. <`0.33 \textwidth`.

(I want to create all figures if possible in "real" size directly to avoid different font sizes later when they would be scaled by the `\includegraphics[width=...]` command).

I wondered how the width of the figures should be - compared to the `textwidth`.
For large figures, the question was already discussed here [Typographic conventions for width of figures in LaTeX data analysis reports](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5351/typographic-conventions-for-width-of-figures-in-latex-data-analysis-reports) and there was an interesting and detailed answer from Geoffrey Jones.

The question not discussed there is:

- How much free horizontal space should be left between figures, of 2, 3 or 4 of them are shown as subfigures over the `textwidth`?

So:

- Is there a typographic rule (or rule of thumb) stating, how much free space is at least "necessary" to visually separate different subfigures?

Comment: I suspect there is no strict rule for this. Add as much space as needed to make it look good. I'd start with `\quad` and `\qquad`. This, of course, depends on how much border space do the figures have themselves.

Comment: sure, the border space is a very important point - it might be a difference, if the figure is a photograph or a line art with much white space around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no fixed rules - not that I know of in any case. As I was working on something different when your question came up I am including some images to show you what looked right in this particular case.

In my eyes a single "em" space is more than enough. Spacing the figures apart makes the page look unbalanced.

[image][image][image][image]

In the first page the space between the figures is 5% of `\textwidth`, the rest one space. I prefer the more compact last ones. I suggest you experiment with different spacing to see what is right for you.