# Tabular: title above and caption below?

Tags: tables, captions

I have a table that I would like to put the Title above and a caption below. Intuitively (though I know how troublesome intuition can be in something like LaTeX), I should be able to do as below:

```
\begin {table}[H]
\caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25in}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.85in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
{\bf Variable Name} & {\bf Regression 1} & {\bf Mean} & {\bf Std. Dev} & {\bf Min} & {\bf Max}\\ 
\midrule
text        &  text     & text      &  text     &  text     &text\\

\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}
\caption {Should be a caption}
\end{center}
\end {table}
```

The above produces:

```
              Table 1: Table Title
===================================================
Name   Regression 1   Mean   Std. Dev.   Min  Max
---------------------------------------------------
text    text           text    text     text   text
===================================================
         Table 5: Should be a caption
```

How can I force latex to suppress the numbering/create a "caption" in the regular sense?

Comment: [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table) provides convincing arguments for captions above tables.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use default text for the second "caption". However,you shouldn't use the table environment, if you do not want to float the tabular. Use a minipage instead and also `tabularx` in this case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Table Title} \label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabular}{ C{1.25in} C{.85in} *4{C{.75in}}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Variable Name & \bf Regression 1 & \bf Mean & \bf Std. Dev & \bf Min & \bf Max\\\midrule
text        &  text     & text      &  text     &  text     &text\\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}\par
\bigskip
Should be a caption
\end{minipage}

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Table Title} \label{tab:title2} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C{1in} C{.85in} *4X @{}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\bf Variable Name & \bf Regression 1 & \bf Mean & \bf Std. Dev & \bf Min & \bf Max\\\midrule
text        &  text     & text      &  text     &  text     &text\\
\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabularx}\par
\bigskip
Should be a caption
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for. How do I write the text `Table 1` and `Table 2` in bold face?

Comment: Write after loading the package `caption`: `\captionsetup{font=bf}`

Comment: Hello @Herbert, how can I get Tab 1: Table Title, instead of Table 1: Table Title?

Answer (score 55):

You can do this with the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. It provides a `\caption*` command that makes a caption without a number or entry into the List of Tables.

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table Title}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\\[10pt]
\caption*{The caption without a number}
\end{table}
```

Comment: \usepackage{caption}

Answer (score 21):

You can simply add text within the table environment to make it appear as a caption, like so:

```
\begin {table}[H]
 \caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title} 
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25in}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.85in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in}}
   \toprule[1.5pt]
{\bf Variable Name} & {\bf Regression 1} & {\bf Mean} & {\bf Std. Dev} & {\bf Min} & {\bf Max}\\ 
   \midrule
   text        &  text     & text      &  text     &  text     &text\\
  \bottomrule[1.25pt]
  \end {tabular}
  \\[1.5] %You can adjust how far below the table the text should appear
  Is just like a caption
 \end{center}
\end {table}
```

Comment: Tried a bunch of different caption and footnote techniques just to end with a solution that was this simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use another tabular with one column:

```
\begin {table}[H]
\caption {Table Title} \label{tab:title} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.25in}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.85in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.75in}}
\toprule[1.5pt]
{\bf Variable Name} & {\bf Regression 1} & {\bf Mean} & {\bf Std. Dev} & {\bf Min} & {\bf Max}\\ 
\midrule
text        &  text     & text      &  text     &  text     &text\\

\bottomrule[1.25pt]
\end {tabular}
\begin{tabular} 
\small Should be a caption
\end {tabular}
\end{center}
\end {table}
```