# npround (seems to) destroy rules for caption in table

Tags: tables, captions

I'm struggling with this one. In essence, I would like to 
place [the caption above the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/tabular-title-above-and-caption-below) but also to have the 
'Table 1' appear at the beginning *and on the same line* as the caption. Finally, I would like to have that the caption is left justified (as usual) instead of being centred (as now).

Now, normally, I know how to do these things, but the inclusion of the `numprint` package seems to make all my rule of thumbs useless: regardless of 
where I put the `\begin{center}` `\end{center}`, the caption is centred. The caption also always appears one line below the 'Table 1' text.

```
\usepackage{numprint}
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{1}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r| n{3}{1}  n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l|}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e1}}&\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\textbf{e2}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e3}}\\ 
  \hline
\textbf{e1}&&&1.712682&(0.9381452)&2.768738&(1.646461)\\
\textbf{e2}&0.5613594&(0.4711274)&&&1.959158&(1.001164)\\
\textbf{e3}&185.9336662&(2.1302318)&140.417800&(1.797353)&&\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\caption{this data table}
\end{table}
\npnoround
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean...  I place a textwidth rule, to show the margin extent, and create a command `\leftcaption` to place the caption there.  I had no problems with the word "Table 1" and the caption being on the different lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{numprint}
\newcommand\leftcaption[1]{\caption{#1\protect\rule{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}{0in}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.1ex}

\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{1}
\begin{table}[ht]
\leftcaption{this data table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|r| n{3}{1}  n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l| n{3}{1} n{3}{1} l|}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e1}}&\multicolumn{2}{ c| }{\textbf{e2}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{e3}}\\ 
  \hline
\textbf{e1}&&&1.712682&(0.9381452)&2.768738&(1.646461)\\
\textbf{e2}&0.5613594&(0.4711274)&&&1.959158&(1.001164)\\
\textbf{e3}&185.9336662&(2.1302318)&140.417800&(1.797353)&&\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1}
\end{table}
\npnoround

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: do you think the table1 bein on a different line could be causes by the imsart env? If yes, would you know how I can switch this particular behavior off?

Comment: @user1933 I can't say I understand your questions. I can only say that the above code I provide compiles on my system using pdflatex. The fact that your "Table 1" and its caption appeared on different lines when you presented your original question is disconcerting.

Comment: sorry. So your code runs, but it now prints the caption on the left of the table (still below the Table 1 titles). Would you know how to remove the 'Table 1' altogether?

Comment: @user1933  Well, you could say `\newcommand\leftcaption[1]{#1\protect\rule{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}{0in}}` instead of the way I show it in my example.  However, if you don't use the `\caption` feature, it will not show up in the list of tables.

Comment: actually, thanks to your example, I found an alternative solution. I will post it below.

Comment: @user1933  Excellent.  Glad to have spurred your thoughts.