# Defining table location in document

Tags: tables, numbering

I've created a table in my document with the help from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/tabular-title-above-and-caption-below)

the table looks exactly as I want except it's location in my document , how can I define the location of the table anywhere in the doc ?

- I remembered that I also want to change the Roman numbering of my tables to regular numbers ??

[image: htbp]
[image: H]

the first screen shot is with [htbp] the second is with [H].
the first one does fits my needs , but why I get this empty space between the text and the section title "SUMMARY & CONCLUSIONS" ?

Comment: I don't really follow. Move the table in the code and it will (likely) move in the PDF. Regarding the second questions, tables are by default (in the most common document classes) numbered with Arabic numbers, so you have likely done something to make the numbers Roman.

Comment: I want it to be right after specific paragraph

Comment: In that case, move it there, add `\usepackage{float}`, and use `H` as the float specifier (i.e. `\begin{table}[H]`). Cf. [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2281)

Comment: Then don't let it float: put it in a center environment, and use `\captionof` (defined the `capt-of` and `caption` packages) to reference it.

Comment: The _only_ reason to use a `figure` environment is to allow latex to move it to help with page breaking, an image that needs to be part of the paragraph flow should just be included with `\includegraphics`

Comment: addressing the blank space: do you by chance have `\newpage` or its equivalent at the end of that paragraph?  since there's only one paragraph on that page, if you don't have `\raggedbottom` set and you have an explicit page break, the only permissible place to stretch the page content is between the heading and the paragraph.  (if there were two paragraphs, the space would be split, and half inserted above each.)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the document:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Right at the place in the code (after a specific paragraph), put it like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
...
\end{table}
```

Click [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures) for more information on the floating options (H, h, etc...).

Comment: Seems to partially work , table is placed at the right place, and the figures that suppose to be right after it are placed after text that should conclude them. also something wired happened to the next section. I'll add screen shot

Comment: Have you tried `[H]` instead of `[htbp]`?

Comment: yes, it's spread the figure on two columns in the second page

Comment: The figure took over the two columns of the page? That would have nothing to do with the `float` of the figure environment, but the scale of the graph. Could you share a screenshot? --- If you use `[H]`, the table or figure will be forced to appear between the corresponding lines of code and/or text. So the rest of the document will adapt accordingly, and that might lead to empty space in the final document (eg. figure too big to fit in a previous page, so it jumps to next page, and so text is moved along because it inevitably goes below the figure).

Comment: I've added screen shots, why I am getting this blank space between the title and the text, i've tried to change the width , but it doesn't work beside that all of my figure in the file are with the same width with no blank space after them.

Comment: That blank space appears because figures been **forced** to be located one after another (and forced to be before the text). Since there is not enough space for both figures to fit in this column (because of the height of the figures), the figure and therefore the following text are moved to the next column. You can play with the `scale` or `width` of the figures and make them smaller to have them appear together in one column. (The issue here is the height, not the width; but height is reduced when width is reduced.)