# Error: \caption outside float

Tags: floats, captions

When I  add the following table   (table1 shown below) I don't get any error, but when adding table2 (shown below) I get the error i)`\caption outside float. \caption` ii) `Undefined control sequence \caption.` What is the difference between these two table definitions? These two seems same to me.

latex code for table1 :

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| p{2.5cm}| p{2.5cm} | p{2.5cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{AAA} & \textbf{BBB} & \textbf{CCC} \\
\hline
DDD   & 111 & 333\\ \hline
EEE   & 222 & 444\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\caption{Caption1}
\label{table1}

\end{table}
```

................................................................

latex code for table2:

```
begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| p{2.5cm}| p{2.5cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{GGG} & \textbf{HHH} \\
\hline
III                    &              113\\ \hline
JJJ                    &              234\\ \hline
KKK                    &              345\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Caption2}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The second lacks a \ in `begin{table}[h]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The second table started with

```
begin{table}[h]
```

instead of

```
\begin{table}[h]
```

meaning it missed a `\` and that was what gave the error of a caption outside a float.

Answer (score 22):

Check carefully your document when such errors pop out; before the editing to the question, the second `begin{table}` wasn't preceded by the backslash. In this case LaTeX is happy to print "begintable[h]" and then start the `center` environment.

If you had proceded on by hitting return at the error message you'd have seen another one telling you that the `document` environment had been closed by `table`.

By the way, don't use the `center` environment in this situation:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
<table data>
\caption{The caption}\label{thelabel}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Should a table caption not be placed [above the table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table)? Not that this is made easy by LaTeX.

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's a style decision. The standard classes provide for captions below in both cases (they set `\belowcaptionskip` to zero). Think to a paper where there are tables and figures side by side: captions will be set *all* above or below. The **caption** package has the options `position=top` and `position=bottom` that can be set separately for figures and tables.