# The space between the table and its caption is very small

Tags: tables, spacing, captions

I have a table written like this:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}
    \hline&Column 1&Column 2\
        \hline\hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
    \hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\\hline  
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A test caption}
    \label{tab:attempt1}
\end{table}
```

Now the caption is VERY NEAR the table.. Additionally, there's a big vertical white space after the caption... How can I fix that to look like any normal table with a caption?

This is the case only with tables, figures are working fine.

[image: The caption is very close to the table, and the following text is so far underneath]

Comment: This is not the default behaviour. Which packages are you using and what `\documentclass`?

Comment: Since the space is as expected in the `article` class, you should probably specify which class you're using.

Comment: how about `\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}`?

Comment: It appears that you must have some code or package that affects this that you are not showing. Please _always_ supply a complete document that shows the problem. `article` class puts a skip of size `\abovecaptionskip` above the caption, and sets this length to 10pt, so you should get at least that spacing. But you may be using a different class.

Comment: This behavior is standard for a KOMA clas because a table gets the caption above instead of below. Of course you can change it via option.

Comment: Thanks cmhughes, this solved the problem! 
I was using llncs class (I am collaborating with someone in this, I've just knew it is not a default one). However it is much easier to write cmhughes' code instead of having to go through the class.

Comment: in the ams document classes, it is expected that captions for tables will be placed above the table, and for figures, below the figure, and space is inserted accordingly.  if the captions are placed in the "opposite" position (below tables or above figures), no intervening space is provided.  so identifying the document class you are using is essential.

Comment: @cmhughes You should turn your comment into an answer.  Also the following link might be useful to add to the answer: [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243/2693)

Comment: Since there is pages and pages of information before the actual best answer: either add `\medskip` or `\vspace{0.1in}` before the caption.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You could try

```
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
```

in your preamble. On another note, have a look at [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table)

Comment: If you have an existing import of `caption`, note that this works only without `tableposition=top`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to affect `listing` captions from `minted`

Answer (score 46):

My attention was drawn to this question by [another one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7658) that had been posted on TeX-LaTeX Meta.  In spite of having been asked almost six years ago, not only—IMHO, of course!—is this question still attracting [poor answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424272), it also lacks a satisfactory answer among all those that have been posted so far, *including* the previous version of this one.  This claim might sound as harsh criticism and obviously needs adequate justification, which I’ll try to provide below; but I want to make it clear at the outset that, since the spacing around captions can depend on many interrelated factors (the choice of the document class, in the first place), a comprehensive analysis of the problem would lead us too far.  In this answer, I’ve chosen to concentrate on how the `caption` package can help to control that spacing, also overriding, if necessary, the decisions made by the document class.

As I said, this answer is an extensive modification of a previous, clearly unsatisfactory version, which corresponded, more or less, to what is now the section covering the use of the `caption` package with the `article` class.

---

## Spacing Around Captions: The Rôle of the Document Class

As [David Carlisle remarked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/the-space-between-the-table-and-its-caption-is-very-small#comment123766_58674) a few minutes after the question was posted, the behavior described therein is not what the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `books`) do; shortly after, [Barbara Beeton added](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/the-space-between-the-table-and-its-caption-is-very-small#comment123773_58674) that the AMS classes (`amsart`, `amsbook`, `amsproc`) do produce a similar output when the caption of a table is placed *below* the table itself, since they assume that only in `figure`s the caption occurs at the bottom, while in `table`s (and in all other other types of floating objects) it is placed at the top.  (See, for instance, `amsart.cls`, lines 1401–1408.)  Other document classes make a similar assumption, so you will incur in a similar problem, when using those classes, if you insist on captioning tables at the bottom, as the standard classes expect you to do.  The [`llncs` class](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip) is one of them (see `llncs.cls`, l. 789–799 and l. 811–820).  We choose to demonstrate only the behavior of `amsart` and of `article`.

### The “native” behavior of the `amsart` class

The following source

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}



\begin{document}

In figure~\ref{fig:sample} the caption is below
and in table~\ref{tab:sample} it is above:
with the \textsf{amsart} class, they both look right.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab:inverted} has the caption below:
with the \textsf{amsart} class, the spacing is wrong.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

yields the following output:

[image: <code>amsart</code> class, “native” behavior]

When the caption is below the table, the spacing is wrong.  This is similar to the OP’s case.

### The “native” behavior of the `article` class

Source code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}



\begin{document}

In figure~\ref{fig:sample} the caption is below
and in table~\ref{tab:sample} it is above:
with the \textsf{article} class, the former looks right,
but the latter does not.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

On the other hand, table~\ref{tab:inverted}, which has the caption below,
looks right with the \textsf{article} class.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>article</code> class, “native” behavior]

Although even the standard classes allow you to customize, by changing the values of the two style parameters `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`, the vertical space above and below the captions, they make the unfortunate assumption that *all* types of caption are placed in the same position (either all above, or all below) with respect to the object they refer to.

---

## Remedies

We already hinted at the fact that several remedies are possible, but that we’ll stick to a few simple ones, based on the `caption` package.  But first, let’s see why I deem the already existing answers unsatisfactory.

### Drawbacks of the other answers

The [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58684) (which has got, as of this writing, 44 votes!) is simply wrong, in general, as you can readily verify, for example in the case of the `amsart` class, if you apply it to the sample source code given above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt plus 0.01pt}
%\captionsetup{tableposition=above}

\makeatletter

%\renewenvironment{table}
%  {\@float{table}}
%  {\end@float}
%\renewenvironment{table*}
%  {\@dblfloat{table}}
%  {\end@dblfloat}

\newcommand*\DrawHoriLine{%
  \par
  \dimen@ \prevdepth
  \kern -.1\p@
  \hrule \@height .1\p@ \@depth .1\p@
  \kern -.1\p@
  \prevdepth \z@
  \null
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \prevdepth \dimen@
}

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

In figure~\ref{fig:sample} the caption is below
and in table~\ref{tab:sample} it is above:
with the \textsf{amsart} class, they both look right.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \DrawHoriLine
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
  \DrawHoriLine
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \DrawHoriLine
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \DrawHoriLine
\end{table}

Table~\ref{tab:inverted} has the caption below:
with the \textsf{amsart} class, even if we apply @cmhughes' answer,
the spacing is wrong.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \DrawHoriLine
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
  \DrawHoriLine
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This code issues some diagnostic messages that helps you verify the claims we are going to make; for the same reason, it also draws thin horizontal lines that mark the exact boundaries of the floats, to make unwanted vertical spaces between the caption and the edges of the float clearly visible.  Note that we have made the vertical space introduced by the solution clearly recognizable in diagnostic messages by adding to it a bit of stretchability.  Moreover, you can try by yourself different alternatives (*e.g.*, try the efficacy of the solution with the `llncs` class) by suitably uncommenting certain lines of code (while commenting out other ones).

It is evident that the accepted answer does not work with the `amsart` class; it might nonetheless give the impression of being adequate in the case of the `llncs` class, but it isn’t either; indeed:

- it introduces spurious spaces between the caption
  and the edge of the float;
- in spite of what the `caption` package claims in
  a warning issued during the compilation,
  the look of the captions *is* changed and differs
  from that specified by the document class.

Note that the second point does not apply to the `amsart` class (because it is one of the classes the package is aware of).  With the `llncs` class, however, the fact that the look of captions is not preserved can be a problem, and one might prefer, for this reason, to avoid the `caption` package altogether.  Actually, in this case the simplest thing to do, if one insists on captioning tables “from below”, is probably to restore the original definition of the two environments `table` and `table*`, as given in the `article` class (on which `llncs` is based).  This is achieved uncommenting the lines

```
%\renewenvironment{table}
%  {\@float{table}}
%  {\end@float}
%\renewenvironment{table*}
%  {\@dblfloat{table}}
%  {\end@dblfloat}
```

in the code shown above.  Since I’m struggling (once more!) with the 30000 character limit, I’ll leave to you to check that what I’ve just said is true, as well as to try other possible alternatives, by suitably commenting/uncommenting parts of that code.  After all, the `llncs` class is not a part of the standard distributions, and I want this answer to focus on solutions that work with the standard classes.  Let me draw attention, however, to an additional drawback of the accepted answer: it sets the skip between the caption and the table to a value that ignores the setting made by the document class.  For example, the `amsart` class uses 12pt, not 10pt.

I find [@isk27’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365220) and [@agold’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371750) defective in similar ways: besides suggesting a patch that needs to be applied to each float individually, they ignore the style parameters preset by the class.  The `center` environment, in particular, yields too much space.

### Using the `caption` package

Actually, simply loading the `caption` package should solve the issue: see section 2.6 of its manual, beginning on page 13.  Note that the command

```
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
```

specifies the value of the skip between the caption and the captioned object, and should be used only if you want to alter the value preset by the document class, which, as already remarked, is not always a good idea.  One should say, rather,

```
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
```

but this is not needed in simple circumstances, because the default setting `position=auto` is usually capable of guessing automatically where the captions occurs (above or below the floating object).  Should this fail, besides the declaration shown above, you can also use the following shortcut, which also works, when you load the package:

```
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
```

See section 5 of the manual of the `caption` package for information on how the package interacts with some known document classes.  Complete, compilable examples, which illustrate its behavior with the `article` and the `amsart` classes, and also show how you can override the general settings for a particular table, follow in the next sections.

The strategy that the `caption` table uses to adjust the vertical space around captions sometimes swaps the meaning of the style parameters `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`; all the examples in the next sections print the values of those parameters, to help you understand what the package is doing.

---

## `article` Document Class

Recall that, with `article`, you need to change the default behavior if you want to caption tables “from *above*”.

### `article` + `caption`, default settings

In this case, usually, the `caption` package is smart enough to insert the correct spaces in all cases, even if you include an exceptional table that is captioned differently from the others; however, this is not guaranteed to work in all situations.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
%
% The following should generally suffice...
\usepackage{caption}
%
% ... but if it doesn't, use, for example, the "tableposition" option:
% \usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
%
% Other packages follow:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Now figure~\ref{fig:sample} (with the caption below)
and table~\ref{tab:sample} (with the caption above)
both look correct.  Remember that we are using the
\textsf{article} class.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

An exceptional table that, like table~\ref{tab:inverted},
has the caption below, is still handled correctly, if we
we do \emph{not} specify to the \textsf{caption} package
any positioning option for captions (the default
\texttt{position=auto} remains in force).
However, this is not guaranteed to work in all situations.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>article</code> + <code>caption</code>, default settings]

### `article` + `caption` + `tableposition=above`

If you explicitly specify `tableposition=above`, however, an exceptional table with the caption below will *not* be handled correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
%
% The following should generally suffice...
% \usepackage{caption}
%
% ... but if it doesn't, use, for example, the "tableposition" option:
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
%
% Other packages follow:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Now figure~\ref{fig:sample} (with the caption below)
and table~\ref{tab:sample} (with the caption above)
both look correct.  Remember that we are always using
the \textsf{article} class.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

If the \textsf{caption} package is explicitly loaded
specifyig \texttt{tableposition=above}, though,
an exceptional table that, like table~\ref{tab:inverted},
has the caption below, will \emph{not} be handled correctly.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>article</code> + <code>caption</code> + <code>tableposition=above</code>]

Such an exceptional table can still be coped with by means of a `\captionsetup` command issued in the body of the floating environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
%
% The following should generally suffice...
% \usepackage{caption}
%
% ... but if it doesn't, use, for example, the "tableposition" option:
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
%
% Other packages follow:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Now figure~\ref{fig:sample} (with the caption below)
and table~\ref{tab:sample} (with the caption above)
both look correct.  We are always using the \textsf{article} class.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Even when \texttt{tableposition=above} has been specified,
an exceptional table that, like table~\ref{tab:inverted},
has the caption below, can still be dealt with by means
of a \verb|\captionsetup| command issued in the body of
the floating environment.  This is guaranteed to work.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{position=below}
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>article</code> + <code>caption</code> + <code>tableposition=above</code>, with exception]

---

## `amsart` Document Class

Recall that, with `amsart`, you need to change the default behavior if you want to caption tables “from *below*”.

### `amsart` + `caption`, default settings

With `amsart`, the default setting imply that all floats except `figure`s (in particular, all `table`s) should be captioned above.  Unfortunately, with `amsart` the `caption` package does not handle correctly an exceptional table that is captioned the other way round.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
%
% The following should generally suffice...
\usepackage{caption}
%
% ... but if it doesn't, use, for example, the "tableposition" option:
% \usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
%
% Other packages follow:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Remember?  With the \textsf{amsart} class,
figure~\ref{fig:sample} (with the caption below)
and table~\ref{tab:sample} (with the caption above)
both looked correct; the same happens if we load the
\textsf{caption} package, as we are doing now.
So, loading the package seems useless in this case,
but it does not harm.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Unfortunately, with the \textsf{amsart} class,
an exceptional table that, like table~\ref{tab:inverted},
has the caption below, will \emph{not} be handled correctly,
if we load the \textsf{caption} package without specifying
any positioning option for captions (thereby leaving
the default \texttt{position=auto} in force).

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>amsart</code> + <code>caption</code>, default settings]

### `amsart` + `caption` + `tableposition=above`

This is the same as the case of the previous subsection.  Of course, you can still cope with an exceptional table with the caption below by means of a `\captionsetup` command issued in the body of the floating environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % I’m accustomed to always loading it...
%
% The following should generally suffice...
% \usepackage{caption}
%
% ... but if it doesn't, use, for example, the "tableposition" option:
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
%
% Other packages follow:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\PrintSkips[1]{%
  \typeout{In #1:}%
  \typeout{\@spaces above: \the\abovecaptionskip}%
  \typeout{\@spaces below: \the\belowcaptionskip}%
}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Remember?  With the \textsf{amsart} class,
figure~\ref{fig:sample} (with the caption below)
and table~\ref{tab:sample} (with the caption above)
both looked correct; the same happens if we load the
\textsf{caption} package, as we are doing now.
So, loading the package seems useless in this case,
but it does not harm.

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
  \caption{A sample image}
  \label{fig:sample}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \PrintSkips{table}
  \caption{A sample table}
  \label{tab:sample}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

However, the \textsf{caption} package is still useful in that
an exceptional table that, like table~\ref{tab:inverted},
has the caption below, can correctly be dealt with,
even when the package is loaded with \texttt{tableposition=above},
by means of a \verb|\captionsetup| command issued in the body
of the floating environment.

\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{position=below}
  \PrintSkips{inverted table}
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
    Titles & Data 1 & Data 2  \\
    \midrule
    This is the first row & 12 & 34  \\
    This is the second row & 56 & 78  \\
    This is---guess what?---the third row & 90 & ?? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with a caption below}
  \label{tab:inverted}
\end{table}

Random text follows, just to fill the page up.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: <code>amsart</code> + <code>caption</code> + <code>tableposition=above</code>, with exception]

Note that the same workaround should be applied also if the `caption` package is loaded with default setting (try it).

Comment: This is very comprehensive and convincing, but I think it would be extremely helpful to have a "TL;DR: Do this" at the top. In my case, I was using `amsart` and wanted `\usepackage[tableposition=below]{caption}`

Answer (score 11):

Try this before caption:

```
    \bigskip
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer because it is simple and actually works. Tip: use `\medskip` for a slightly smaller spacing.

Comment: `\smallskip` is also available

Comment: Thank you for this brief answer :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Genius

Comment: Such a cute answer. Short and sweet. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I have found that using `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` instead of `\centering` does add more space between the caption and the table:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}
    \hline&Column 1&Column 2\\
    \hline\hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\\hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\\hline  
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption{A test caption 2.}
    \label{tab:attempt2}
\end{table}
```

This results in:

[image: table using center]

However, as commented before, when no special packages/settings are used the normal output already has sufficient space:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}
    \hline&Column 1&Column 2\\
    \hline\hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\\hline
    cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\\hline  
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A test caption.}
    \label{tab:attempt1}
\end{table}
```

[image: table with centering]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution that worked for me is adding `\vspace{...}` before the caption. This is how it looks:

[image: image showing the caption 0.1cm further away from the table]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|r|r|}
  \hline Monopole & No  & \#1 & 5 & 482 106 m \\
  \hline Yagi-Uda & Yes & \#1 & 4 &  86 903 m \\
  \hline Yagi-Uda & Yes & \#2 & 4 & 108 642 m \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\caption{Position accuracy of experiment 3}
\label{tab:exp3results}
\end{table}
```

---

Thanks to [isk27's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365220/107500) for nudging me in the right direction! I tried adding vspaces in other places but didn't get it to work until I saw that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

People who have the same problem, but use KOMA-Script and it's *scrreprt* document class and place the caption above the table need to add the option `captions=tableheading` to the document class options:

```
\documentclass[...,captions=tableheading]{scrreprt}
```

This adjusts the formatting of the table title and adds vertical space below it. By default the table title is expected to below the table and therefore no vertical space is added below it. Note that you still need to "manually" put `\caption{...}` above `\begin{tabular}...`. The above option only changes the formatting but not the position.

Comment: Excellent - very good to know.

Answer (score -1):

I suffered from the same problem. Finally, I found the cause was from package `subfig`, changing setting from `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` to `\usepackage[caption=true]{subfig}` can resolve problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is right to downvote, here.  As far as I can tell, the `subfig` package is not an essential part of the problem, although it could interact with it in particular situations.  I think that, in order for your answer to be helpful, you should at least explain *how* and *when* this interaction occur.