# Too little space between table and caption

Tags: tables, captions

Why is there so little space between my table and its caption? Is this normal?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Some words ...}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
and yet some & more words & to see the space problem \\
Here is a & second row. & It is a table.
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I found [The space between the table and its caption is very small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/the-space-between-the-table-and-its-caption-is-very-small) where the OP faced the same problem, but did not provide a full MWE.

Comment: I think that `\usepackage{caption}` will solve your problem. Edit: this is also the solution to the problem of the question you linked.

Comment: as mentioned @PhelypeOleinik, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Some words ...}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
and yet some & more words & to see the space problem \\
Here is a & second row. & It is a table.
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}` will add space between caption and table. size of space you can adjust with caption option `skip=...`

Comment: @Zarko Should this question be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: My question was not *how* to solve the problem, but *why* it occurs and if this is normal.

Comment: @Joe Oh, sorry. Well... *normal* it is, you aren't using any packages and I got the same result. Why, I guess that's because when TeX is typesetting paragraphs, a `\baselineskip` separates one line from another, but in this case you can a `\caption` right on top of a `\begin{tabular}`, and possibly they don't have (without the `caption` package) an amount of space that should separate them, so TeX puts one box right on top of the other, making the "space" between them so narrow. Someone who knows stuff will tell you if I just wrote a lot of garbage or not :)

Comment: Put some letter with a descender, like `qypgj` in the caption to see the space grow :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, this question has been for already asked, but i'm the worst searcher on the site for this :-(. if you know one, please go ahead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the space between caption and table depends on the document class.

`article` (and all the basic latex classes) assume that captions in floats are
always below the content, and insert space above it, not below it.  that's
appropriate for figures, but not for tables.

other document classes (e.g. `amsart`) make a different assumption, that in a
`figure` environment, the caption is below the figure, but in a `table`
environment, the caption is at the top and space is inserted between caption
and table proper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround for the standard classes such as `article`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\@floatboxreset{\check@table}
\newcommand{\check@table}{%
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\@captype}{table}
   {% exchange \abovecaptionskip with \belowcaptionskip
    \dimen@=\abovecaptionskip
    \abovecaptionskip=\belowcaptionskip
    \belowcaptionskip=\dimen@
   }
   {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Some words ...}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
and yet some & more words & to see the space problem \\
Here is a & second row. & It is a table.
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]