# Missing, number treated as zero. Multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Here is my code.

```
 \begin{tabular}{*{5}{|c}|}
 \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{c|}{Independent Variable} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Chi-Square Results} \\
 \cline{2-5}

& \multirow{3}{c}{Gender newline\ Female & newline\ Male} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Alcohol Use} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Chi-Square Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{P-Value} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Sig
 } \\
 \cline{2-5}
```

This the code error that I am receiving.

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 

l.204 ...}{Gender newline\ Female & newline\ Male}
```

I am trying to make this table.

[image]

What should I change to make the table above.Is there an easier way to code this?

Comment: `\newline` is the command.

Comment: You need `\&` for the literal ampersand. `\multirow{3}{c}{Gender newline\ Female \& newline\ Male} ` (But, of course, you may not want 'newline' literally, as @Sigur says.)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you need `\multirow` for the table shown in your picture. After carefully examining the picture, it seems that the logical structure of the table should be as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l r r r r r}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Independent Variables}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Chi-Square Results}} \\
\cmidrule{3-6}
        &        & Percent Obese & Chi-Square Value & $P$-Value & Sig. \\
\midrule
\textbf{Gender} &                     &        &   $0.002$ & $0.967$ &    \\
                &              Female & $17.4$ &           &         &    \\
                &                Male & $17.4$ &           &         &    \\
\midrule
\textbf{Age}    &                     &        & $522.308$ & $0.000$ & ** \\
                &           Ages~2--5 &  $0.9$ &           &         &    \\
                &          Ages~6--11 &  $9.5$ &           &         &    \\
                &         Ages~12--19 & $34.8$ &           &         &    \\
\midrule
\textbf{Race}   &                     &        &  $30.329$ & $0.000$ & ** \\
                & White, non-Hispanic & $12.9$ &           &         &    \\
                & Black, non-Hispanic & $22.4$ &           &         &    \\
                &               Other & $18.5$ &           &         &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: chi-square results]

Some useful tips for you:

- [Never use vertical rules and never use double rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238516/164314). The previous linked thread also provides numerous tips for creating beautiful tables.
- When presenting scientific numerical results, avoid using [Oldstyle Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures), and put them in math mode so they are automatically [Lining Figures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/lining-figures) (well, most of the time).
- If you have `.967`, write `0.967`. Never omit the zero! Don’t waste [the invention of zero](https://theconversation.com/nothing-matters-how-the-invention-of-zero-helped-create-modern-mathematics-84232).

Answer (score 2):

I propose two realizations of your table; in either case no `\multirow` is necessary and a single column is used in place of your first two. The horizontal size of the table is smaller, helping for readability.

```
\documentclass{article}

% these are only for the second table
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
%%%

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

% for the second table
\newcommand{\Tsplitcell}[1]{%
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A caption for the table}\label{a-label}

\begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries\splitcell{Independent \\ Variables}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries Chi-Square Results} \\
\hline
& \% Obese & $\chi^2$ Value & $P$-Value & Sig. \\
\hline
\textbf{Gender}           &        &   $0.002$ & $0.967$ &    \\
\quad Female              & $17.4$ &           &         &    \\
\quad Male                & $17.4$ &           &         &    \\
\hline
\textbf{Age}              &        & $522.308$ & $0.000$ & ** \\
\quad Ages 2--5           &  $0.9$ &           &         &    \\
\quad Ages 6--11          &  $9.5$ &           &         &    \\
\quad Ages12--19          & $34.8$ &           &         &    \\
\hline
\textbf{Race}             &        &  $30.329$ & $0.000$ & ** \\
\quad White, non-Hispanic & $12.9$ &           &         &    \\
\quad Black, non-Hispanic & $22.4$ &           &         &    \\
\quad Other               & $18.5$ &           &         &    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{A caption for the table}\label{a-label-bis}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  c
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\Tsplitcell{Independent \\ Variables}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Chi-Square Results} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& {\% Obese} & {$\chi^2$ Value} & {$P$-Value} & Sig. \\
\midrule
\textbf{Gender}           &        &   0.002 & 0.967 &    \\
\quad Female              & 17.4 &           &         &    \\
\quad Male                & 17.4 &           &         &    \\
\midrule
\textbf{Age}              &        & 522.308 & 0.000 & ** \\
\quad Ages 2--5           &  0.9 &           &         &    \\
\quad Ages 6--11          &  9.5 &           &         &    \\
\quad Ages12--19          & 34.8 &           &         &    \\
\midrule
\textbf{Race}             &        &  30.329 & 0.000 & ** \\
\quad White, non-Hispanic & 12.9 &           &         &    \\
\quad Black, non-Hispanic & 22.4 &           &         &    \\
\quad Other               & 18.5 &           &         &    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `caption` package if the table captions are at the top?

Comment: @RuixiZhang Stylistic opinion

Comment: I see. My suggestion was based on [this comprehensive answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424725/164314) in the post [The space between the table and its caption is very small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58674/164314). My initial thought on the caption was that it was not properly spaced.