# IEEE has formatting problem for table

Tags: tables, ieeetran

Hello I am trying to fit a table into half column for a IEEE paper.
In order to replicate the problem I prepared a small example:

This is what I have so far but this is the **incorrect** behavior, notice the absence of spaces between the caption and the absence of space between the table and the paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % v3!
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}


%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

% Some paragraphs........

\section{Systematic literature review}\label{sec:systematic_review}

\subsection{Analysis of publication data}

Wacker (1998), who identiﬁed two broad macrocategories of research methods (analytical and empirical) further divided
into six categories (analytical: conceptual, mathematical and statistical; empirical: experimental design, statistical sam-
pling and case studies). The classiﬁcation developed by Wacker has already been used by Burgess, Singh, and Korogl
    
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}L{0.8}L{1.1}L{1.1} @{}}
    \toprule
Type of document    &   Frequency  &   Proportion (\%) \\
    \midrule
    Journal   &   930   &   23\% \\
    Conference Proceeding   &   168   &   23\% \\
    Book series   &   111   &   23\% \\
    Book   &   5   &   23\% \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Types of retrieved documents for 3D ultrasound query}
\label{tab:values}
\end{table}

Wacker (1998), who identiﬁed two broad macrocategories of research methods (analytical and empirical) further divided
into six categories (analytical: conceptual, mathematical and statistical; empirical: experimental design, statistical sam-
pling and case studies). The classiﬁcation developed by Wacker has already been used by Burgess, Singh, and Korogl
```

I am looking for a behavior that occupys the column ad that provides the proper IEEE spaces, an example is like the one below, notice the proper spacing:

[image]

I order to solve the problem I went on the official website of overleaf (which is the editor I am using) and studied [this reference](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) which I applied but could not really arrive to what I am looking for.

Also after searching I came across [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58674/the-space-between-the-table-and-its-caption-is-very-small) which helped but up to a certain point.

I don't understand what I am missing. Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: we can't run the code fragment you have posted and the spacing is due to code not shown so it is hard to comment.  The space above and below should be `\intextsep` which you can set with `\setlength`  but no idea why it is so small in your image.

Comment: How or where is the `L` column type defined?

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle, and thanks for stopping by. I just added the additional packages I am using so the example should be complete to replicate. Let me know if you need additional details, and thanks for reading the question :)

Comment: Don't set \Intextsep=0pt.  That is typically only done with wrapfig, which you shouldn't be using anyway.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks for the input! After eliminating `\Intextsep=0pt` I have the proper spacing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEEtran require that table captions are above table. So, your MWE (a bit modified) should be something like this:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx} % consider is v3

\begin{document}
\section{Systematic literature review}\label{sec:systematic_review}

\subsection{Analysis of publication data}

Wacker (1998), who identiﬁed two broad macrocategories of research methods (analytical and empirical) further divided
into six categories (analytical: conceptual, mathematical and statistical; empirical: experimental design, statistical sam-
pling and case studies). The classiﬁcation developed by Wacker has already been used by Burgess, Singh, and Korogl

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Types of retrieved documents for 3D ultrasound query}
\label{tab:values}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=2.0{\,\%}] 
                }
    \toprule Type of document        &   {Frequency} &   {Proportion (\%)}   \\
    \midrule
Journal                 &   930         &   23\,\%          \\
Conference Proceeding   &   168         &   23\,\%          \\
Book series             &   111         &   23\,\%          \\
Book                    &   5           &   23\,\%          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

Wacker (1998), who identiﬁed two broad macrocategories of research methods (analytical and empirical) further divided
into six categories (analytical: conceptual, mathematical and statistical; empirical: experimental design, statistical sam-
pling and case studies). The classiﬁcation developed by Wacker has already been used by Burgess, Singh, and Korogl
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case, that you have available `siunitx` package version 2, than specification for additional space for `\,`% `in o`S` columns is slightly different:

```
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Types of retrieved documents for 3D ultrasound query}
\label{tab:values}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=3.0]
                S[table-format=2.0,
                  table-space-text-post={\,\%}] % when you have installed siunitx version 2}
    \toprule Type of document        &   {Frequency} &   {Proportion (\%)}   \\
    \midrule
Journal                 &   930         &   23\,\%          \\
Conference Proceeding   &   168         &   23\,\%          \\
Book series             &   111         &   23\,\%          \\
Book                    &   5           &   23\,\%          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. I have [a strange error](https://i.imgur.com/BjjUa3p.png). How do I solve this?

Comment: @Emanuele, hm, it seems that Overleaf hasn't recent version of `siunitx` package. I would add solution for older version (v2) ASAP.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem using `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` but didn/t work, is there a temporary solution?

Comment: @Emanuele, see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help, it works!