# What are some best practices for the typography of tables and figures?

Tags: floats, typography, best-practices

I put captions above my tables and below my figures. I use the `booktabs` package (and no vertical lines) for my tables.

Do I show both tables and figures (graphs) for the same data? If so, in what order?

In general, should I use `[h]`, `[t]`, or `[b]` at all? When I should I use them? Is it okay for several floats to stack up on a page by themselves?

Is it necessary to have a list of tables and a list of figures? If so, where? At the beginning (after the table of contents)? At the end of each chapter? At the end, before the index? (My particular use case is a thesis, but answers for all document types are appreciated.)

**EDIT**: Also, where should tables and figures be placed in the source document? Definitely within the same section that references the table or figure, but in general before, in-between, or after the paragraphs in question?

Comment: My general rule of thumb for all of your questions would be: consistency. As to question #4, I think it is more usual to put the lists of tables and figures after the table of contents, but there may be other convenient solutions. Regarding question #3, most classes handle the problem by setting a maximum number of floats and how much of the page they can take, which should do most of the work; then you should fine-tune things in your *final* draft by specifying `[h]`, `[t]`, `[b]` or `[p]` where needed (wrong placement, extra white space, etc.).

Comment: Geoffrey Jones submitted a nice piece a while back explaining why [captions above tables and below figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table/3253#3253) is the preferred layout style. Worth a read I think (not only because it mentions dolphins).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*If you are writing a thesis, look at the style your university is demanding (or else you will be shooting your own feet)*

Nevertheless, these are my opinions:

**General**

You are doing it right by putting captions -- above for tables and below for figures. And use of `booktabs` and ditching vertical lines adds to the taste.

Showing both tables and graphs for the same data may be subjective. If you want to display the exact values and also the trend of variation, both will help. If you have too much data, then showing them through a graph will be a better idea (Reviewers don't read/like too much data). Further, space constraints influence this issue to some extent.   Personally I am against showing both.

**Thesis (report or book)**

In a big document like thesis, it will be better to put the figures and tables close to where they are mentioned in text. By using the options `[htb]` you are giving latex more freedom to adjust float placement (at which latex is good). Stacking several floats in the same page is only a matter of personal preference and as long as it doesn't destroy readability, I don't find any thing wrong in it.

Also, it will be better to have a LoT and LoF if you have a large number of those things. It will make navigation much easier. They are generally put in the front matter (place where your certificates, preface/abstracts come), after the table of contents.

**Article**

*If you are submitting your article to a journal/conference, beware of the style they want. If it is the case, you don't have freedom but to use their style file.*

As space may become a constraint here, putting both graph and table should be avoided. 
Whatever is written above for figures is still valid for floats, here also. Now the inclusion of LoT and LOF will become a matter of personal preference. As your manuscript may not grow beyond, say, 20-25 pages, I feel that they won't be necessary.

Comment: Me personally, I have better experience with float placement `[tp]`. Generally I find `[h]`-placed floats disturbing (it breaks the text flow) and bottom-placed ones look strange (which is really only a personal feeling), as well, a single page with both `[t]` and `[b]` floats is a non-sense (when this happens). Of course except Figure/Table attachment, where the rules are different.

Answer (score 12):

Answers to your questions:

1. **Captions below or above?**

   Figures have captions below, table and all other objects
   have the caption above.

   Argumentation for this: for tables it is important to know what kind of data you are handle with. So it is better to place the heading at the top of the table (specially the table is two ore more pages long). In a figure the image is more important than the heading. You want see first the picture. If it is not clear you might have a look to the heading.

   I personally do not like side heads, because they usually generate too much white space. This results in poor greyscale and does not facilitate the reading.

   If you are using package `hyperref` use the package
   option `hypcap=true` (links on figures will show image and caption).
   Use `booktabs` and do not use vertical lines.
2. **Show both data and image?**

   It depends on the data and images: if the reader needs to have an
   overview I would show the figure in the text (table could be in ithe
   appendix), if the data is needed to recalculate your given formulas
   I would show the table in the text (figure could be in appendix). If
   table and figure are importand for the reader show the more
   importand one first.
3. **Usage of `[h]`,`[t]`,`[b]` and `[p]`?**

   Use `[h]` not without `[t]` or `[b]` (`[ht]`), that would throw a warning. Use them for your final work (everything is written, now you have a look to good typography).

   Because each image or table has to be referenced in your work, give all references to tables and figures like this: See `table~\ref{tab:name}` and see `figure~\ref{fig:name}`. Because table and figure are floating never reference them with "see the table above" (you can't be sure it will stay there!).

   Use `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` to force floats to be printed before the next chapter starts. If possible do not have only floats on on page (include more text) and do not use `[p]`.
4. **Position and sequence of lists in document**

   It depends on the style of your university. But in general I would always print a list of figures and tables. If the list or lists are very important for your work, i would print them at the beginning of my work, if the are not so important, you can print them later.

*One possible* sequence could be:

- Title,
- Dedication, Preface,
- Contents,
- List of Figures, (either here)
- List of Tables,  (either here)
- other lists,     (either here)
- your work,
- List of Figures, (or here)
- List of Tables,  (or here)
- other Lists,     (or here)
- Bibliography,
- Index

Comment: I'd be much obliged if you could provide a concrete reference backing up your statement that figures should always have captions below and [other floats] above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Perhaps you can add this to your explanation. Also I suggest you don't write that tables _always_ have captions above and figures _always_ have captions below because because it seems a personal advice. As a matter of fact, I don't think it's true that your advice is the norm. For example, it excludes captions to the side.

Comment: IIRC Bringhurst doesn't mention captions explicitly in the “Elements of Typographic Style”.

Comment: @cgnieder But he does have captions to the side of his tables and figures.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: there's no "preferred norm" on this kind of thing, so it is useless to try finding one. And it is not *his* preference, it is a standard typographic rule, and contrary to many others, it has solid arguments in its favor instead of being arbitrary. It goes without saying that other styles are possible, but that does not make them better or preferred, whoever uses them.

Comment: @Philippe Goutet If this is a standard typographic rule, hen why does Bringhurst not implement it and why do I have lots of _beautiful_ books with captions to the side?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: something you seem not to have considered is *why* Bringhurst is putting captions in the margin: it's because he has a wide enough one. And captions are not the only thing he puts in the margin as many pages have short comments in it. This is a special style which is neither appropriate nor possible in all documents. And what Kurt proposes is not specific to German typography, it's also done in French typography. And it is possible in all documents, so it's certainly a much more *general* rule than Bringhurst's.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet You're missing my point. Kurt should mention his opinions are from a German point of view, which he isn't.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: You've missed my point too, which is that his point of view is not German centric. And Bringhurst is not the alpha and omega of English or American typography (his book is an influential introductory text, but still an introductory text). If I take a journal about typography which I have on my bookshelf, as the *Penrose Annual* #66 (1973), they have the captions of the figures in the margin (page 213), or just below the figures (page 211), but the captions of the tables are just above it (page 222).

Comment: @Philippe Goutet I don't think I missed any point. I'm very open to _any_ opinion. For example, I mentioned that I agreed mostly with Kurt. My only problem is the way Kurt phrases his answer. It's as if his is the alpha and omega view on this topic, with which I disagree. all I'm looking for is some more nuance. I provided several suggestions as to why Kurt should consider rephrasing his answer but to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

Don't fiddle with the placement options for floats unless you know *exactly* how the algorithm works - i.e. you have read *and* understood Lamport's description. And *iff* you fiddle with them, do so *after* you have finished the content, i.e. when you are fine-tuning your document.

See also [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2283/5763) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5763)

Comment: Yes, you don't want to spend time trying to force a float to appear at a certain position, then later find it has moved to some spurious position because you have added stuff above it.

Comment: @User17670: So why no upvote? `:-)`