# Problems aligning on a decimal in a table with colored rows

Tags: tables, formatting

I'm having a problem with making a "pretty" table

The intent is to have alternating light background colors with black text for normal rows to facilitate reading across, with the header having a blue background and white text to make it stand out, and having numbers line up on the decimal, with "nominal" columns being separated by vertical lines

I think these are the relevant lines of LaTeX code

```
\usepackage{color,colortbl}

\renewcommand{arrayrulewidth}{1.5}

\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}

\begin{table}{!htbp}
\large
\begin{caption}
\begin{tabular}{|r@{.}l|r@{.}l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 2 header}}} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
-0&333 & 1&444 \\
\rowcolor{evenrowcolor}
1&001 &  10.02 \\
\rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
0& & 401&32 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{\label{table:example} Some caption.}
\end{table}
```

The problems I have are

1. `\rowcolor` isn't playing nice with the align on decimal stuff (splitting the "nominal" column at the decimal and doing `r@{.}l` for the alignment of "actual" columns making up a "nominal" column) basically the left half of the smallest digit in the left (with alignment `r`) actual column and the decimal point are being hidden
2. the vertical lines are showing up double thick in the header (twice as thick as in the normal rows)

I greatly appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

By the way, I'm compiling with a version of `pdflatex` that shipped with `redhat 5.X` (not sure what X is and I can't upgrade the machine's LaTeX because I'm not an administrator and it has to be compiled on this machine).

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem

Answer (score 7):

This seems like the perfect application for the [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) package's `S` column type, which I have used below as

```
    \begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.0]|}
```

[image]

The `S` type takes an optional argument in which you can specify formatting options; I have used

```
table-format=<number of integers before decimal>-<number of integers after decimal>
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{SIunitx}
    \label{table:example} 
    \begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=1.0,parse-numbers=false]|S[table-format=3.0,parse-numbers=false]|S[table-format=3.2]|S[table-format=3.0]|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 2 header}}} \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
        -0 & 333 & 1     & 444 \\
        \rowcolor{evenrowcolor}
        1  & 001 & 10.02 &     \\
        \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
        0  &     & 401   & 32  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Some other notes:

- The reason for the 'double thickness' was because you specified the vertical line twice, once in each `\multicolumn`; remove one of them (as I have done above) and you'll see the thickness just as 'single'
- I've used `\centering` which is preferable to `center` as discussed in [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)
- I put the caption above the `table` as discussed in [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table)
- a lot of folks would recommend *not* using vertical lines; see the `booktabs` documentation for examples.

If you don't have access to the `siunitx` package, then you can achieve a similar result using the `dcolumn` package, as shown below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{dcolumn}
    \label{table:example} 
    \begin{tabular}{|d{0}|d{0}|d{2}|d{0}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 2 header}}} \\
        \hline
        \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
        -0 & 333 & 1     & 444 \\
        \rowcolor{evenrowcolor}
        1  & 001 & 10.02 &     \\
        \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}
        0  &     & 401   & 32  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[cmhughes' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82510/16595) remains valid, but I guess you wanted an output like this (although you missed one `.` in your code where an `&` should have been).

---

I also added an example (at the beginng) that uses `xcolor`'s `\rowcolors` command to get alternating row colors, so you don't have to apply them manually (what would you have done if you had twenty rows?).

It has three obligatory parameters:

- the first line that gets the odd-row color,
- the odd-row color, and
- the even-row color.

```
\rowcolors{1}{evenrowcolor}{oddrowcolor}
```

The first row's color will be overwritten by its own `\rowcolor` command.

---

Loosely related to you question I added examples of tables that

- don't use lines and colors

  - only colors
  - only horizontal lines provided by the `booktabs` package (which produce in my eyes a cleaner/prettier output, but your mileage may vary)
- highlights the uses of the `table-format` options by `siunitx`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\centering % for this example

{%
\rowcolors{1}{evenrowcolor}{oddrowcolor}%
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=+1.2]S[table-format=3.3]}
    \rowcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}} & {\color{white}{column 2 header}} \\
    -0.333                                                 & 1.444                            \\
    1.001                                                  & 10.02                            \\
    0                                                      & 401.32                           \\
\end{tabular}%
}

\vspace{2.4em} % for this example
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=+1.2]S[table-format=3.3]}
    \rowcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}} & {\color{white}{column 2 header}} \\
    \rowcolor{oddrowcolor} -0.333                          & 1.444                            \\
    \rowcolor{evenrowcolor} 1.001                          & 10.02                            \\
    \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}  0                              & 401.32                           \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2.4em} % for this example
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=+1.2]|S[table-format=3.3]|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{headercolor}{\color{white}{column 1 header}} & {\color{white}{column 2 header}} \\ \hline
    \rowcolor{oddrowcolor} -0.333                          & 1.444                            \\
    \rowcolor{evenrowcolor} 1.001                          & 10.02                            \\
    \rowcolor{oddrowcolor}  0                              & 401.32                           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2.4em} % for this example
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=+1.2]S[table-format=3.3]}
    \toprule
    {column 1 header} & {column 2 header} \\ \midrule
    -0.333            & 1.444             \\
    1.001             & 10.02             \\
    0                 & 401.32            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2.4em} % for this example
\begin{tabular}{
    S
    S[table-format = 2.2]
    S[table-format = 2.2(1)]
    S[table-format = +2.2]
    S[table-format = 2.2e1]
}
    \toprule
    {Values} & {Values} & {Values} & {Values} &  \\ \midrule
    2.3      & 2.3      & 2.3(5)   & 2.3      & 2.3e8   \\
    34.23    & 34.23    & 34.23(4) & 34.23    & 34.23   \\
    56.78    & 56.78    & 56.78(3) & -56.78   & 56.78e3 \\
    3,76     & 3,76     & 3.76(2)  & +-3.76   & e6      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @cmhughes Yes and no. If I understand the OP correctly (and based on his code), he was aiming for an output closer to my example as he was aligning the integer part and the decimal part at `r@{.}l` (although he has one `.` left in his code where an `&` should have been).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for all your help, Qrrbrbirlbel was right about aligning on the decimal.  The machine I need to do this on does not have siunitx installed on it so this is the solution I'm going with (I didn't know of dcolumn so thanks for that a quick google search turned up a pdf document that mentioned using D{.}{.}{-1} would center it on the decimal rather than right justify it with N decimal places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.392,0.584,0.929}
\definecolor{oddrowcolor}{rgb}{0.961,1.000,0.980}
\definecolor{evenrowcolor}{rgb}{0.902,0.902,0.980}
\definecolor{white}{rgb}{1.0,1.0,1.0}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\begin{document}

{
\rowcolors{1}{evenrowcolor}{oddrowcolor}
\begin{tabular}{|d|d}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}\color{white}{column 1 header}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{headercolor}\color{white}{column 2 header}} \\
-0.333                                                 & 1.444 \\
1.001                                                  & 10.02 \\
0                                                      & 401.32 \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```