# Force caption to go above/below with biblatex

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, memoir, floatrow

I have used the following to force captions above (tables) and below (figures) as per [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
(tabular material)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with the `biblatex`.

Is it possible to force all captions to be above/below with `biblatex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\let\newfloat\relax` before loading `floatrow` seems to do the trick.

EDIT: The "No room for a new `\count`" error that seems to be caused by the combination `biblatex`/`floatrow` can be resolved by adding

```
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{20}
```

at the start of the preamble.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{20}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\let\newfloat\relax
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
(tabular material)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It sure does. I guess my MWE wasn't good enough. The problem arises when using `biblatex` and `floatrow`.

Comment: @Josso Then you have to provide a *real* (short, compilable, shows the problem) MWE.

Comment: I've updated with a MWE. I get two different errors based on whether or not I include your redefinition of `newfloat`.

Comment: how old is your `memoir`? Current `memoir` autoload the `etex` package if found

Comment: @daleif Maybe loading the `etex` package is superfluous -- using `\reserveinserts{20}` seems to make a difference, though.

Comment: dalief: I'm using (Mac)TeXLive-2012, so I'd guess it should be pretty up-to-date. 
@lockstep That does indeed help, and I actually rediscovered that today. While trying to use bigfoot, I stumbled upon [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/no-room-for-a-new-dimen) which helped with the bigfoot-package as well as the floatrow-package.