# Figure is chopped off when inserting a MATLAB table as eps figure

Tags: tables, floats, eps, matlab

I am trying to include a `MATLAB UI` table (which I have previously saved as an `.eps` figure and put it into the same folder as my `.tex` file) into a LaTeX document, using:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Table_TEST1}        %{Figure name without .eps extension}
\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:Test1Table}
\end{figure}
```

However, only a part of the figure appears, one quarter of the figure is chopped off. I tried to use

```
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{Table_TEST1}
```

instead, the figure is rescaled but one part of the figure is still missing. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

When I open the `eps` figure  using an `eps` viewer, it says that the dimensions are:
    width:470, height:293.

I don't know if this fact is playing a role in the problem.

Comment: What was your [export procedure](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) to get .eps from Matlab ? is it possible to provide the `problem-sample.eps` to test ? Did you test with `other.eps` figure ? are you using TeXlive(eps to pdf conversion automagic) or MiKTeX(`\usepackage{epstopdf}`) ?

Comment: to get the .eps file, I am just saving the matlab figure (Table_TEST1.fig) as a .eps figure (Table_TEST1.eps ) directly into Matlab. Then I copy-paste the file into my tex folder. However, after doing some Research online, I figured  that I needed to compile the document using pdfLatex instead of just latex. Now the figure is no longer chopped up. My only question now is, since my figure is really a Table, I can't seem to find a way to have a caption that says for instance Table 2, instead of Figure 9. And the reason why Ithink is because I did not create that table directly in latex.

Comment: I repaced \"begin/end" {figure} with \"begin/end"{table)  and used `\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics{Table_TEST1} \caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:Test1Table}
\end{figure} and it is working now!

Comment: you are superfast. `latex-->dvi-->ps2pdf` is somewhat an old way these days unless you need it for `ps specials` `pstricks` etc. `pdflatex`has become the default engine for many people and editors including TeXworks etc. your [figure in table example](https://www.writelatex.com/99397lmvkrq) is shown via writelatex. Hope this is fine.

Comment: shall i make an answer with our comments, if it satisfies  you.

Answer (score 1):

Try matlab2tikz script into matlab.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, e.g., by showing a usage example. In its current form, your answer is probably of little help due to its brevity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile this sequence `latex`-->`dvi`-->`ps2pdf` to include `.eps` figure and output `.pdf`. Simple`latex` gives only `.dvi` and pdflatex gives directly `.pdf`. BTW `latex`-->`dvi`-->`ps2pdf` is a traditional way unless you need it for ps specials,pstricks etc. `pdflatex` has become the default engine for many people and editors including TeXworks etc.

When your figure is really a Table, to have a Table caption that says for instance `Table No`, instead of `Figure No`,

Just include your `Table_TEST1` figure without extension inside the Table environment like below example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}%figure without extension
\caption{Test1Table as figure}
\label{fig:Test1Table}
\end{figure}
 This is example for figure enviroment \ref{fig:Test1Table}.
 %http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243/15717 (why table caption is on the top)
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Test1Table as table} % table caption at top and separate counter 
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
\label{tabl:Test1Table}
\end{table}
This is example for figure inside table enviroment \ref{tabl:Test1Table}.
\end{document}
```

[image]