# "align" inside "table" because of table caption - how to do pagebreak?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, align

I have a table:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{align}
\nonumber
b_{1}  & = 0,200                   & \beta_{1}  & = z                           \\
\nonumber
b_{2}  & = 0,022                   & \beta_{2}  & = q                           \\
\nonumber
b_{3}  & = z                       & \beta_{3}  & = 0                           \\
\nonumber
b_{4}  & = 0,024                   & \beta_{4}  & = (3/2)\cdot\pi               \\
\nonumber
b_{5}  & = 0,052                   & \beta_{5}  & = z                           \\
\nonumber
b_{6}  & = 0,067                   & \beta_{6}  & = z                           \\
\nonumber
b_{7}  & = 0,008                   & \beta_{7}  & = z                           \\
\nonumber
b_{8}  & = z                       & \beta_{8}  & = \pi                         \\
\nonumber
b_{9}  & = b_{7}                   & \beta_{9}  & = (3/2)\cdot\pi               \\
\nonumber
b_{10} & = b_{6}-b_{4}             & \beta_{10} & = (3/2)\cdot\pi               
\end{align}
\caption{table 1}
\label{tab 1}
\end{table}
```

The table continues with more lines. The reason why I formatted it in "align" is because I wanted aligned equal signs and I would have to add $ everywhere because of math. Than I wrapped it in "table" cause I needed table caption.

Problem comes with lenght of the table. I tried to use `\allowpagebreaks` but it won't break since it is inside of the table. Then I tried to use longtable but it didn't work with align inside. I also tried to put blank table with caption under "align", but tex sometimes puts the table elsewhere and also in list of tables there should be the number of the page where the table begins I suppose.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why have someone deleted the solution using caption package which was there yestarday? It was quite constructive but only problem was that it ruined paragraph indent.

Comment: Maybe because it ruined paragraph indention? Do you remember who posted it?

Comment: "cmhughan" or something like that.

Comment: So I guess [@cmhughes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes). You could ask him in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) next time he is around.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a `caption`, you don't actually *have* to put it in a float- you can use the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package which provides the command

```
\captionof{table}{Your caption goes here}
```

The `captionof` stands for 'caption outside float', but handily you can also read it as 'caption of'.

In the example below I have used the [`geometry`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry) package simply to change the page size so that you can see that the `allowdisplaybreaks` works as intended.

To fix the problem with paragraph indentation being set to zero after the caption, place the `\captionof` command within a pair of braces (`{\captionof{figure}{...}}`).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

{\captionof{table}{My caption goes here}\label{tab:anythingyouwant}}
\begin{align*}
    b_{1}  & = 0,200       & \beta_{1}  & = z             \\
    b_{2}  & = 0,022       & \beta_{2}  & = q             \\
    b_{3}  & = z           & \beta_{3}  & = 0             \\
    b_{4}  & = 0,024       & \beta_{4}  & = (3/2)\cdot\pi \\
    b_{5}  & = 0,052       & \beta_{5}  & = z             \\
    b_{6}  & = 0,067       & \beta_{6}  & = z             \\
    b_{7}  & = 0,008       & \beta_{7}  & = z             \\
    b_{8}  & = z           & \beta_{8}  & = \pi           \\
    b_{9}  & = b_{7}       & \beta_{9}  & = (3/2)\cdot\pi \\
    b_{10} & = b_{6}-b_{4} & \beta_{10} & = (3/2)\cdot\pi 
\end{align*}

Here's a reference: \ref{tab:anythingyouwant}.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, that could help, but is there a possibility of `\label`? And I think that does not solve the problem with number of the page where the table ends in list of tables if I put the caption under the table.

Comment: @PavelSnabl have updated with `listoftables` and `ref`, both are as expected :) Note that table captions should be *above* tables, as discussed in [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243)

Comment: I find it logical to place the caption above the table now. But I think that using caption package does not support referencing. Am I right that putting a blank table with caption and label would be better in this case?

Comment: @PavelSnabl I'm not sure what you mean- my MWE contains a reference which works as expected- don't forget to compile twice :) No need for a blank/empty table :)

Comment: sorry, it works fine now. But one think that does not suit me is the small vertical space between text and caption and big space between caption and table. But that´s probably how it should be...

Comment: it is not possible to put the caption and label inside the align to prevent the uneven spacing right?

Comment: @PavelSnabl the vertical space is partly from the caption, partly from the `align` environment- I think you might be better off using a `table` and using the `aligned` environment within it- page breaks are going to be a problem though

Comment: Unfortunately the page breaks are necessary for me. And today I found another problem about your solution - all paragraphs under the caption are without indent, which is quite a big problem.

Comment: @PavelSnabl I edited cmhughes' answer with a fix to the paragraph indentation issue.