# Table on top or bottom

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I am currently discussing with a colleague whether to put a table on top or bottom in proper documents (e.g., research paper). I once learnt to put figures on top and tables on bottom. I actually prefer this placement as the caption of a figure is on top and then it integrates much better with the main body. Would love some insights here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, I think this question is off-topic or depends on personal opinions.

Comment: Why is that off-topic? Layout specific questions get answered quite regularly here. For example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table

Comment: In my point of view this not layout specific. There will be some different opinions where to place a table or a figure, to put the caption above or below or to the side or use a footnote only.

Comment: You can ask on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com . This kind of question is wellcome there ...

Comment: Does it matter? As long as it is clear, it will be fine for submission. Your views will have no influence on the layout if the article is accepted as any journal or conference or whatever will impose its own style on the published version. And, by the way, the placement of the caption relative to the table or figure is not written in stone anyway.