# How to generate a table as below?

Tags: tables, longtable, supertabular

[image]

I try to generate a table like this using {longtable} and {supertabular} but failed. Anybody can help?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}     
\begin{supertabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline 
        Size & Lethal to & Number  & Trackable & Produces Lethal Fragments  \\
        & Operational & in& &When Impacting An  \\
        & Spacecraft &Orbit & & Operational Spacecraft \\
        \hline
        Small & (Usually) Not & Millions & No & No\\
        (<1cm) && &  & \\\hline
        Medium  & Usually & ~500,000  & No & Maybe\\
        (1cm - 10cm)&  & in LEO &  & \\\hline
        Large & (Almost) Always & ~22,000 & Yes & Yes - 100s to 10,000s\\
        (>10cm)&& && \\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post what you tried?

Comment: Will it really be a long table (breaking across pages)?

Comment: The spacing seems a bit odd and i find the colour pretty distracting.

Comment: First step: hold your typographical nose

Answer (score 8):

An alternative using `booktabs` for the table rules, `tabularx` to get a table that fits the textwidth and `siunitx` to properly typeset the units.

[image: vinntonSpacecraftTabular]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}     
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XC{.18\linewidth}XXC{.3\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    Size & Lethal to Operational  Spacecraft & Number in Orbit & Trackable & Produces Lethal Fragments When Impacting An  Operational Spacecraft \\
    \midrule
    Small (\SI{<1}{\centi\meter})           & (Usually) Not     & Millions             & No   & No\\\addlinespace
    Medium (\SIrange{1}{10}{\centi\meter})  & Usually           & $\sim$500,000 in LEO & No & Maybe\\\addlinespace
    Large (\SI{>10}{\centi\meter})          & (Almost) Always   & $\sim$22,000       & Yes  & Yes -- 100s to 10,000s\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I took the liberty to add `$\sim$` to your code. In your version, the tilde didn't show up...

Comment: @habi oh, i completely overlooked those. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if I want to add a title below this table? Seems that \caption{} didn't work...

Comment: @Vinnton Shure it does. You'll have to embed the `tabularx` inside a `table` environment, as so: https://gist.github.com/habi/f4ec705147dbb86e7275. As per [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3253/828) *I* place the captions above the tables.

Answer (score 6):

If you absolutely want some colour, here are two solutions with swapping rows and columns. One with vertical and horizontal rules, the other with only horizontal rules (built *not* using `booktabs`, as this leads to white spaces in coloured cells). The latter looks better, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, supertabular, makecell, hhline, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\blankcell{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}}}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{supertabular}{| >{\columncolor{Burlywood1!80}}Sl|*{3}{Sc|}}
        \cline{2-4}
\blankcell & \multicolumn{3}{Sc|}{Size}\\
 \hhline{~|---|}
\rowcolor{DarkSeaGreen3}\blankcell & Small (<\,1cm) & Medium (1cm--10cm) & Large (>\,10cm) \\
        \hline
      \eqparbox{C1}{Lethal to\\ Operational Spacecraft} & (Usually) Not & Usually & (Almost) Always \\
        \hline
        Number in Orbit & Millions & \makecell{\textasciitilde\,500,000\\ in LEO} & \textasciitilde\,22,000 \\
        \hline
   Trackable & No & No & Yes\\
        \hline
        \eqparbox{C1}{ Produces Lethal Fragments \\When Impacting an\\ Operational Spacecraft} & No & Maybe & Yes -- 100\,s to 10,000\,s \\
        \hline
\end{supertabular}

\vskip1cm
\begin{supertabular}{ >{\columncolor{Burlywood1!80}}Sl*{3}{Sc}}
\cellcolor{white}& \multicolumn{3}{Sc}{Size}\\
 \hhline{~---}
\rowcolor{DarkSeaGreen3}\cellcolor{white} & Small (<\,1cm) & Medium (1cm – 10cm) & Large (>\,10cm) \\
        \Xhline{0.8pt}
      \eqparbox{C1}{Lethal to\\ Operational Spacecraft} & (Usually) Not & Usually & (Almost) Always \\
        \hline
        Number in Orbit & Millions & \makecell{\textasciitilde\,500,000\\ in LEO} & \textasciitilde\,22,000 \\
        \hline
   Trackable & No & No & Yes\\
        \hline
        \eqparbox{C1}{ Produces Lethal Fragments \\When Impacting an\\ Operational Spacecraft} & No & Maybe & Yes -- 100\,s to 10,000\,s \\
        \Xhline{0.8pt}
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that in the first table you have two`Sc|`   surplus.

Comment: @Zarko: Oh! yes. Thank you, I'll correct it at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What if I want to add a title below this table? Seems that \caption{} didn't work...

Comment: For `\caption` you need to put table into `table` environment. Or, if you like to have table direct in text, than you should use `\captionof {table}{ table title }` and ad in preamble package `caption` or `capt-of`.

Comment: @Vinnton the question for a caption is a different one and should be posted as such. You wrote that question two times, here and under my answer. Two people reacted, one of them not knowing that the question is already answered.