# Table jumps to top

Tags: tables

I have a Page a Chapter and some Text. Then I add a table after my text.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Entwicklungsmöglichkeiten}
\label{Entwicklungsmöglichkeiten}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
 Text& Text& Text& Text\\ \midrule
 \textbf{Text}& - & ++ & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - &  ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& ++ & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - & ++ \\ \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The table jumps above my text chapter!

Questions:

- How can I avoid that?
- How can I make the table as wide as the page?
- How can I put the Caption of the table to the bottom of it?

Comment: Use a specifier in the third bracket after `\begin{table}`. Replace `\begin{table}[]` with `\begin{table}[h]`.

Comment: super, that worked - the table is now on its place. The other two questions? :) Caption on bottom - like on figures(images) and the width of the table? thank you very much

Comment: move the caption entry after `\end{tabular}`

Comment: ok worked too! thx

Comment: You asked, "How can I make the table as [wide] as the page?" I assume that you wish to make the table as wide as the *text block*, rather than as wide as the page itself. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that table captions are typically placed above the table, as you had it, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243/586 (If you were aware of this, sorry for the noise.)

Comment: Concerning the table position, there is a lot more info on the topic in the three highest questions tagged with [tag:floats] and [tag:positioning]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats+positioning

Comment: @TorbjørnT. wow no I didn't know that. interesting.

Comment: as clearly seen in the images in mico's answer, making the table full width makes it much harder to read, it just introduces unwanted white space making it much harder for the eye to locate the column/row associations, just centering the natural width table would be much easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two main options for setting the width of the tabular material to `\textwidth`:

- Use a `tabular*` environment.
- Use a `tabularx` environment.

`tabular*`, when used in conjunction with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`, works by modifying the amount of intercolumn whitespace. `tabularx` works by changing the widths of columns of type `X`. 
Both options are illustrated in the following screenshot and option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}
\toprule
 Text& Text& Text& Text\\ \midrule
 \textbf{Text}& - & ++ & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - &  ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& ++ & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - & ++ \\ \midrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Entwicklungsmöglichkeiten}
\label{Entwicklungsmöglichkeiten}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXXX@{}}
\toprule
 Text& Text& Text& Text\\ \midrule
 \textbf{Text}& - & ++ & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - &  ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& ++ & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& + & - & ++ \\
 \textbf{Text}& -- & - & ++ \\ \midrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Weitere Entwicklungsmöglichkeiten}
\label{WeitereEntwicklungsmöglichkeiten}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't use it :/ ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \documentclass

Comment: @PomeGranate - Did you place one or more `\usepackage` statements *after* `\begin{document}`? Please advise.

Comment: thx for the hint. Its my first latex document. Worked! THX!

Comment: last Q: Is it possible to make the first column a bit wider? or as wide as its content is? -really last question! :D

Comment: @PomeGranate - How much wider do you want the first column to be?

Comment: As wide as its content, so that there is no linebreak in the cell? otherwise lets say a number: 4cm?

Comment: @PomeGranate - "As wide as its content, so that there is no linebreak in the cell": that's as wide as it is with the `tabular*` approach. It's actually *less wide* than the present `tabularx` approach (because the first column only contains `\textbf{Text}` for now). If you don't want to allow linebreaks, stick with the `tabular*` approach.