# How can i draw long table in latex?

Tags: tables

Hello I am trying to draw long table in latex in two pages. I have used longtable package but still every thing is overlapped on one another. It looks like in picture.
My code is as follows:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}[H]
    \centering
      \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
   \begin{tabular}{ |p{3.5cm}||p{3.3cm}|p{3.3cm}|p{3.3cm}| }
\hline
System parameters  &Steady state simulation at cell voltage 1.35\si{V} &Steady state simulation at cell voltage 1.35\si{V} &Transient simulation \\
 \hline
a   &0.075  &0.075  &0.075\\
fv  &823.15 &823.15 &823.15\\
dsf &136720.0729    &136720.0733    &136720.073\\
ff  &60929.13415    &67052.77939    &48254.41811\\
ff  &430227.8227&774469.0564&293576.401\\
ff  &6930.843614    &13759.54063    &4397.631169\\
ff) &724.9280926    &759.3822837    &702.3558378\\
ff  &126.9999073    &532.1625423    &138.6410601\\
ff  &3.406775256    &17.32352093    &6.106443651\\
ff  &0.493541105&0.651667849    &0.347160992\\
ffE (\si{mol/s}) &0.179303961   &0.911764259    &0.321391771\\
ff  &778.8335281    &917.5963789    &692.7669968\\
ff  &2.490772357    &2.864034271    &2.667914307\\
ff  &892.1580047    &954.4744642    &857.87485\\
ff  &885.8513695    &942.4909806    &853.6193071\\
ff  &2.133114059    &1.433408993    &1.845442049\\
ff  &1.651490524    &2.866734694    &1.152784727\\
ff&0.436040703  &0.688364718    &0.382576613\\
ff  &0.751203837    &0.837535957    &0.682169459\\
ff  &0.56352883 &0.476290559    &0.518885236\\
ff  &197649.207 &203772.8527    &185392.804\\
ff  &7655.771707    &14518.92292    &5131.232447\\
ff  &126.9999073    &532.1625423    &135.8647496\\
ff  &7782.771614    &15051.08546    &5267.097196\\
ff  &627877.0297    &978241.9092    &480469.8634\\
dg  &7782.771614    &15051.08546    &5267.097196\\
fb  &635659.8013    &993292.9946    &485736.9606\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{nxxxxxxx}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `longtable` environment should replace the `tabular` environment, not surround it. You should reviece a bunch of error messages from your code. Please don't ignore them! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Unrelated, but `1.35\si{V}` should be replaced with `\SI{1.35}{\volt}` or   `\SI{1.35}{\V}`

Comment: Is your table really longer than a single page? To me it looks like it should fit onto a single page, while it indeed could be quite a bit wider than the textwidth.

Comment: Also unrelated to the issue itself: Why do column 2 and 3 share the same column header text? What is the difference between the entries in the two columns?

Comment: yes, the table is quite long. the header is a small mistake. ty for the units correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is your problem (in your MWE the preamble of document is missed). Anyway, see if the following proposition works for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, xltabular}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |l||S|S|S| }
\caption{nxxxxxxx}
\label{tab:my_label}\\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell[t]{System\\ parameters}
    &   \mcx{Steady state simulation at cell voltage \SI{1.35}{V}}
        &   \mcx{Steady state simulation at cell voltage \SI{1.35}{V}}
            &   \mcx{Transient simulation} \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{nxxxxxxx}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell{System\\ parameters}
    &   \mcx{Steady state simulation at cell voltage \SI{1.35}{V}}
        &   \mcx{Steady state simulation at cell voltage \SI{1.35}{V}}
            &   \mcx{Transient simulation} \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\endhead
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
a   &0.075          &0.075          &0.075\\
fv  &823.15         &823.15         &823.15\\
dsf &136720.0729    &136720.0733    &136720.073\\
ff  &60929.13415    &67052.77939    &48254.41811\\
ff  &430227.8227    &774469.0564    &293576.401\\
ff  &6930.843614    &13759.54063    &4397.631169\\
ff) &724.9280926    &759.3822837    &702.3558378\\
ff  &126.9999073    &532.1625423    &138.6410601\\
ff  &3.406775256    &17.32352093    &6.106443651\\
ff  &0.493541105    &0.651667849    &0.347160992\\
ffE (\si{mol/s})   
    &0.179303961    &0.911764259    &0.321391771\\
ff  &778.8335281    &917.5963789    &692.7669968\\
ff  &2.490772357    &2.864034271    &2.667914307\\
ff  &892.1580047    &954.4744642    &857.87485\\
ff  &885.8513695    &942.4909806    &853.6193071\\
ff  &2.133114059    &1.433408993    &1.845442049\\
ff  &1.651490524    &2.866734694    &1.152784727\\
ff  &0.436040703    &0.688364718    &0.382576613\\
ff  &0.751203837    &0.837535957    &0.682169459\\
ff  &0.56352883     &0.476290559    &0.518885236\\
ff  &197649.207     &203772.8527    &185392.804\\
ff  &7655.771707    &14518.92292    &5131.232447\\
ff  &126.9999073    &532.1625423    &135.8647496\\
ff  &7782.771614    &15051.08546    &5267.097196\\
ff  &627877.0297    &978241.9092    &480469.8634\\
dg  &7782.771614    &15051.08546    &5267.097196\\
fb  &635659.8013    &993292.9946    &485736.9606\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
```

- Is your table longer than one page? If not, instead of used `xltabular` table environment you can use `tabularx` which can be inserted into `table` float.
- In above MWE instead of `longtable` is used `xltabular` (which is combination of `longtable` and `tabularx` tables environments).
- for horisontal rulles are used rules defined in the `makecell`package
- numbers are aligned at decimal point by use of the `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package
- I wonder if you really need 9 decimal digits?

[image]

**Edit:**
If you not like to have numbers aligned at decimal points, than replace

```
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |l||S|S|S| }
```

with

```
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |l||*{3}{>{\hskip 3em}X|} }
```

and you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @zarko. It helped me a lot. but is it possible to arrange the data in a straight line?? it is possible to have the caption at the bottom of the table instead of top?

Comment: @VISHNU, see edited answer.

Comment: @VISHNU: Following typorgaphical conventions, a table caption should be placed above a table as opposed to below a table. This is especially true for tables spanning multiple pages. See also: [Why should a table caption be placed above the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3243/134144)

Answer (score 1):

With the folllwing redesign that avoids vertical lines and uses just some horizontal lines in combination with evenly distribued white gaps to act as a guide to the eye, your table easily fits onto a single page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
  \caption{nxxxxxxx}
  \label{tab:my_label}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\thead{System\\ parameters}  
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Steady state simulation \\at cell voltage}}
      & \thead{Transient\\ simulation} \\
      \cmidrule{2-3}
  & \thead{\SI{1.35}{\V}} & \thead{\SI{1.35}{\V}} \\
 \midrule
a                     & 0.075          & 0.075          & 0.075       \\
fv                    & 823.15         & 823.15         & 823.15      \\
dsf                   & 136720.0729    & 136720.0733    & 136720.073  \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 60929.13415    & 67052.77939    & 48254.41811 \\
ff                    & 430227.8227    & 774469.0564    & 293576.401  \\ 
ff                    & 6930.843614    & 13759.54063    & 4397.631169 \\ \addlinespace
ff)                   & 724.9280926    & 759.3822837    & 702.3558378 \\
ff                    & 126.9999073    & 532.1625423    & 138.6410601 \\
ff                    & 3.406775256    & 17.32352093    & 6.106443651 \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 0.493541105    & 0.651667849    & 0.347160992 \\ 
ffE (\si{\mol\per\s}) & 0.179303961    & 0.911764259    & 0.321391771 \\
ff                    & 778.8335281    & 917.5963789    & 692.7669968 \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 2.490772357    & 2.864034271    & 2.667914307 \\
ff                    & 892.1580047    & 954.4744642    & 857.87485   \\
ff                    & 885.8513695    & 942.4909806    & 853.6193071 \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 2.133114059    & 1.433408993    & 1.845442049 \\
ff                    & 1.651490524    & 2.866734694    & 1.152784727 \\
ff                    & 0.436040703    & 0.688364718    & 0.382576613 \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 0.751203837    & 0.837535957    & 0.682169459 \\
ff                    & 0.56352883     & 0.476290559    & 0.518885236 \\ 
ff                    & 197649.207     & 203772.8527    & 185392.804  \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 7655.771707    & 14518.92292    & 5131.232447 \\
ff                    & 126.9999073    & 532.1625423    & 135.8647496 \\
ff                    & 7782.771614    & 15051.08546    & 5267.097196 \\ \addlinespace
ff                    & 627877.0297    & 978241.9092    & 480469.8634 \\ 
dg                    & 7782.771614    & 15051.08546    & 5267.097196 \\
fb                    & 635659.8013    & 993292.9946    & 485736.9606 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```